# Must a zombie hear the wight to be commanded by it?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

So, a [wight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17059-wight) can have up to 12 [zombie](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17077-zombie)s under its command. How does it work? Should it shout to the zombies what it wants? If yes, what's a good range for the zombies to understand its command? I saw a [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98153/what-is-a-persons-hearing-radius), and it's not clear for me what is a reasonable distance for the hearing range.

Comment: Is your question whether or not the other answer applies to a wight and zombies?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The rules do not explain how a wight controls its zombie servants.

All we have is the description in the statblock and the lore section beneath it in the *Monster Manual*, and neither give any details about the nature of the wight’s control over zombies:

> A humanoid slain by this attack rises 24 hours later as a zombie under the wight’s control, unless the humanoid is restored to life or its body is destroyed. The wight can have no more than twelve zombies under its control at one time.

> Humanoids slain by a wight can rise as zombies under its control.

So it’s up to the DM to decide what this means.